# Range Memory Overflow Issue

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, range

Trying to run a simple macro to copy/paste some columns from one worksheet to another. It works fine when I only use a few columns but when I add all the columns I need I get an error. I think my syntax is right but I heard it could be a range/clipboard memory issue.

```
Sub CopyValuesDiff()
Dim sourceWs1, dstWsDiff1, As Worksheet, dtToday As Date

dtToday = Format(DateTime.Now, "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")
Set sourceWs1 = Sheets("Size_1")
Set dstWsDiff1 = Sheets("Diff_1")

sourceWs1.Range("H6:H300, J6:J300, L6:L300, N6:N300, AF6:AF300, AH6:AH300, AJ6:AJ300," & _
"AL6:AL300, BD6:BD300, BF6:BF300, BH6:BH300, BJ6:BJ300, CB6:CB300, CD6:CD300," & _
"CF6:CF300, CH6:CH300, CZ6:CZ300, DB6:DB300, DD6:DD300, DF6:DF300, DX6:DX300," & _
"DZ6:DZ300, EB6:EB300, ED6:ED300, EV6:EV300, EX6:EX300, EZ6:EZ300, FB6:FB300," & _
"FT6:FT300, FV6:FV300, FX6:FX300, FZ6:FZ300").Copy Destination:=dstWsDiff1.Range("B2")

dstWsDiff1.Range("A3").Value = dtToday

Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

Comment: Why this doesn't work? You have correctly written the range address (string). Unfortunately, the string is 366 characters long but there is a limitation of 255 characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Split columns name list into an array

```vb
    Dim aCol, RowCnt As Long, i As Long
    Const S_ROW = 6
    Const E_ROW = 300
    RowCnt = E_ROW - S_ROW + 1
    aCol = Split("H,J,L,N,AF,AH,AJ,AL,BD,BF,BH,BJ,CB,CD," & _
    "CF,CH,CZ,DB,DD,DF,DX,DZ,EB,ED,EV,EX,EZ,FB,FT,FV,FX,FZ", ",")
    For i = 0 To UBound(aCol)
        dstWsDiff1.Range("B2").Offset(0, i).Resize(RowCnt).Value = _
            sourceWs1.Cells(S_ROW, aCol(i)).Resize(RowCnt).Value
    Next
```

---

- Get column index with a nested loop

```
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, iColDst As Long
    Dim iColSrc As Long, RowCnt As Long
    Const S_ROW = 6
    Const E_ROW = 300
    RowCnt = E_ROW - S_ROW + 1
    iColDst = 2
    For i = 1 To 8
        For j = 8 To 14 Step 2
            iColSrc = (i - 1) * 24 + j
            dstWsDiff1.Cells(2, iColDst).Resize(RowCnt).Value = _
                sourceWs1.Cells(S_ROW, iColSrc).Resize(RowCnt).Value
            iColDst = iColDst + 1 
        Next
    Next
```

Comment: Both suggestions ended up working thanks. However it is copying the formulas in the source worksheet. Need to copy just the values. Would that be a `.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues`

Comment: You don't need `PasteSpecial`. I have updated code with a better option.

Comment: Another option is to get column index with nested loop.

Answer (score 2):

your source data has a pattern

you could then use `Union()` method iterating from the "base" range

```
Dim allRange As Range
With sourceWs1.Range("H6:H300, J6:J300, L6:L300, N6:N300")
    Set allRange = .Cells
    Dim i As Long
        For i = 1 To 7
            Set allRange = Union(allRange, .Offset(, i * 24))
        Next
End With
    allRange.Copy dstWsDiff1.Range("B2")
```

Answer (score 1):

Please, also try this very fast way. It uses arrays and `Application.Index` function which is able to return specific columns from an array (in specific places, if necessary...):

```
Sub CopyValuesDiff()
 Dim sourceWs1 As Worksheet, dstWsDiff1 As Worksheet, dtToday As Date
 Dim arr, arrColNo, arrFin 'necessary arrays
 Const strCols As String = "H,J,L,N,AF,AH,AJ,AL,BD,BF,BH,BJ,CB,CD,CF,CH,CZ,DB,DD,DF,DX,DZ,EB,ED,EV,EX,EZ,FB,FT,FV,FX,FZ"

 dtToday = Format(DateTime.Now, "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")
 Set sourceWs1 = Sheets("Size_1")
 Set dstWsDiff1 = Sheets("Diff_1")

 arr = sourceWs1.Range("A6:FZ300").Value 'place all the necessary range in an array
 arrColNo = getArrColsNo(strCols) 'load an array of necessary columns to be returned NUMBERS

 arrFin = Application.Index(arr, Evaluate("row:1" & UBound(arr) & ")"), arrColNo)  ' The necessary final array!

 dstWsDiff1.Range("B2").Resize(UBound(arrFin), UBound(arrFin, 2)).Value = arrFin 'drop the processed array content, at once.

 MsgBox "Ready...": dstWsDiff1.Activate
End Sub

Function getArrColsNo(strCols As String) As Variant 'extract columns numbers
  Dim arrCols, arrNo, i As Long
  arrCols = Split(strCols, ",")
  ReDim arrNo(0 To UBound(arrCols))

  For i = 0 To UBound(arrCols)
    arrNo(i) = cells(1, arrCols(i)).column
  Next i
  getArrColsNo = arrNo
End Function
```